# dynamically setting usercontrol property

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-4.0

I have a user control in asp.net that i need to dynmically set properties for. The propety and property values are in a dictionary, for example:

```
Dictionary<string, string> propertyValues;
Control c = Page.LoadControl("~/Control.ascx")
```

I can currently set the properties on the control using reflection, however, with .net 4 and the new dynamic keyword, is there an easier way to do it, for example, something like this:

```
dynamic c = Page.LoadControl("~/control.ascx");
foreach(var itemin propertyValues)
{
  c.item.key = item.value;
}
```

this obviously doesnt work because item.key is a string and not a property.

thanks
Raj.

Comment: I dont think there is a solution using the dynamic keyword, the best alternative i could come up with is using extension methods to Control and using reflection within the extension methods.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried `c[item.key]` ??? or maybe `c.Properties[item.Key]` ???